# Set functions: function of union of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

I have a doubt about a property of set functions

In detail, I have a set function $\omega$, which I apply to some subsets $S_1$, $S_2$, ...

I noticed that this function has the following property:

$\omega(\{\omega(S_1), \omega(S_2), ...\})  = \omega(\bigcup_i S_i)$

For instance, if $\omega$ is the summation, and $S_1 = \{1,2,3\}$ and $S_2 = \{4,5,6\}$, it holds:

$\sum (\sum(\{1,2,3\}), \sum(\{4,5,6\}))$ = $\sum (\{1,2,3, 4,5,6\})$

The same should hold for functions like minimum and maximum

Can you help me in defining this property? Does it have a particular name?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it works for sum: consider $S_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $S_2 = \{3, 4, 5\}$.